# store each letter of NSString as object of NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an NSString of integer values. I need to add each one of the integers as a separate object in an NSMutableArray.

I tried `characterAtIndex:` but I keep getting errors…

P.s. I've solved over 30 problems thank's to stackoverflow's search, but didn't find any information on this problem.

Comment: Please add more info, so we can provide more precise answers. What your string looks like? How do you need to split it? One digit by one? And what have you been trying, what kind of errors so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
{
    NSString *substr = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)];
    [results addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[substr intValue]];
} 

NSLog(@" %@ separated into: %@", string, results);
```

Comment: Thank's a lot!! Just what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking at `componentsSeparatedByString:` or `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` for your purpose. Both methods are available on `NSString`.

Comment: no go. in my case there are no components that separate objects in the string. Anyway, thank's a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If your integers are more than one digit or are space-separated, consider alternately using an [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - you can read instances of NSInteger off the string one by one, wrap them in NSNumbers, and stick them in your array.

Comment: Sorry, same as jer's answer: I don't have any separators and the numbers are one digit integers. Anyway, thank's a lot for trying to help!

Comment: That's what we're here for :)